# while loop error in Java

Tags: java

well im currently learning java my myself but from what i know i just cant seem to fix this problem
currently testing a script where if u dont type ur name exactly u must re-type it but this error appears i searched everywhere but most of the things i tried dont work

```
Please type in your name: 
lucas
Welcome lucas
Confirm your name:
luca
Please type in your name: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at input.main(input.java:9)
```

here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                System.out.println("Please type in your name: ");
                String name = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Welcome " + name);
                if (name.equals("nico")) {
                    System.out.println("bitch");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Confirm your name:");
                    String name1 = input.nextLine();
                    if (name1.equals("nico")) {
                        System.out.println("Hello " + name1 + "... bitch");
                    } else if (name1.equals(name)) {
                        System.out.println("Thank you");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]

Comment: What input did you use to get the output above? The NoSuchElementException is being raised because `Scanner.nextLine()` is not finding another line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `try-with-resources` to around your `while` loop. When execution leaves the `try-with-resources`, Java closes the *resources*. Here, that resource is the standard input, which cannot be re-opened.

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please type in your name: ");
```

You actually don't really need the `try-with-resources` here. Don't close standard input/output/error.

Comment: And now I learned something today! Documentationf for the interested: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()

Comment: wow i cant belive i didnt notice that... i feel dumb now
but lets say i remove the `try-with-resources` and its left like this:
  `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (true) {
   System.out.println("Please type in your name: ");`

the IDE tells me Resource leaked: the 'input' is never closed. unless i keep the `try-with-resources`

Comment: @lucas That's a warning. You can choose to ignore it. In this case, you should ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the `Scanner` *into* your loop.

Loop while the scanner still has input.

Currently, you *create* `new Scanner` too often.